# Python Interactive Window Error in VS Code - Failed to write file default.profraw: Permission denied

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I recently updated my Anaconda distribution (Conda 4.8.3, Python 3.6.10) and am currently running Visual Studio Code (version 1.44.2).

I tried to open a Jupyter Notebook and a Python Interactive Window but get the following error:

```
Command 'Python: Show Python Interactive Window' resulted in an error Activating Python 3.6.10 64-bit ('base': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: StdErr from ShellExec, LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file "default.profraw": Permission denied
```

Every time I run the python interpreter it creates a new "default.profraw" file in my current directory which did not happen with my previous conda/python installation.

I've tried installing older versions of Python using virtual conda environments, e.g., Python 3.5, to see if it would remedy the error but no luck.

I'm currently using Mac OSX High Sierra (10.13.6)

Comment: that was a bug with a specific conda-forge python which is fixed already. Try updating python.

Comment: xref: https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues/339

Comment: I'm a developer on the Python extension. If updating python doesn't work check out the command "Python: Select interpreter to start Jupyter server" in vscode. That command controls what interpreter we use to launch jupyter with (it doesn't have to match your current interpreter). You can make sure that is set to an interpreter that is able to launch "jupyter notebook" from the terminal without errors.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me crazy! The [link referenced by @cel above](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues/339#issuecomment-612204870) gives the fix, but it should be an answer, not just a link:

> This seems to be new behavior in the 1010 build of Python 3.6.10. 
>   Build 1009, which can be installed using 
>     `conda install -c conda-forge "python=3.6.10=*1009*"`, does not produce this file.

Worked for me!